# processing multiple fastq files with cutadapt

Tags: fastq, shell, cutadapt

I have DNA sample from 5 pools, having 25 fastq files each. I am running cutadapt to remove the primers using this command 
`cutadapt -g ACTTAAGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTG A7_S7_R1_001.fastq -o sb_A7_S7_R1_001.fastq --discard-untrimmed`
However, this is too time consuming.  I tried my hand at writing shell script

```
for file in /dir/*
do
  cmd cutadapt -g ACTTAAGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTG "$file" >> results.out
done
```

But it is not running . 
Can someone help.
Thanks

Comment: I assume you don't really have `cmd` in there. Put and `ls` in just to see which files are seen.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
for file in /dir/*
do
  cutadapt -g ACTTAAGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTG "$file" >> results.out
done
```

Also you have omitted `--discard-untrimmed` from the original command. If you want that as well along with everything to run in parallel:

```
for file in /dir/*
do
  cutadapt -g ACTTAAGTGTATGTAAACTTCCGACTTCAACTG --discard-untrimmed "$file" -o "`basename -s .fastq $file`_out.fastq" &
done
```